# jQuery search set HTML for h6 tags, if empty remove and update source var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My following code reads source data and sets the html in a var, before I action it I need to search the HTML source for any empty h6 tags if any found to remove them and update the source var so can be processed correctly in the other functions.

As the editor is sometimes adding empty `<h6></h6>` so breaking generated tabs, it also sometimes does `<h6><span></span></h6>` so if that's the case would be good to remove that as well.

Example working: https://jsfiddle.net/17cw1kg1/
width empty h6, h6 child span breaks a little: https://jsfiddle.net/17cw1kg1/2/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var originalTabs = $('.originalTabs').html();
    var windowWidth = 0;
    var swapSpeed = 0;
    var scrollSpeed = 0;

    function clearTabs() {
      $('.originalTabs').html(originalTabs);
    }

    //clearTabs();
    //desktopTabs(); 

    function desktopTabs() {
      clearTabs();

      // cretate tabs for desktop
      var headers = $("#tab_description h6");

      $('#tab_description h6').each(function(i) {
        $(this).nextUntil("h6").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="tab" id="tab-' + i + '"/>');
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        $('.tabs').append('<li class=""><a href="#tab-' + i + '">' + headers[i].innerHTML + '</a></li>');
      }

      $('ul.tabs').each(function() {
        var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
        var listitem = $(this).find('li');
        active = listitem.first().addClass('active');
        content = $(active.attr('href'));
        $('.tab').hide();
        $(this).find('a').click(function(e) {
          $('.tab').hide();
          $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');

          content.hide();
          active = $(this);
          content = $($(this).attr('href'));
          active.parent().addClass('active');
          content.show();
          return false;
        });
      });

      headers.remove(); // remove headers from description  
      $('#tab-0').show(); // show the first tab

      $('#tab_description').show();
    }

    function mobileTabs() {
      clearTabs();

      //alert("loaded mobile");

      var headers = $("#tab_description h6");

      $(headers).each(function(i) {
        $(this).append('<a href="#accordion_' + (i + 1) + '" id="accordion_' + (i + 1) + '"></a>');
        //$(this).nextUntil("h6").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="aTab" id="tab-'+i+'"/>');
        $(this).on('click tap', function() {
          tabClick($(this));
        });
      });

      $('#tab_description h6').first().addClass("active");
      $('#tab_description h6').first().nextUntil("h6").show();

      $('#tab_description').show();
    }

    var tabClick = function(x) {
      //alert("clicked");
      var accordionContent = $('#tab_description p, #tab_description ul, #tab_description table, #tab_description div');

      //$('#tab_description h6').removeClass("active");
      if (!$(x).hasClass("active")) {
        $(x).addClass("active");
        $('#tab_description h6').removeClass("active");
        $(accordionContent).slideUp(swapSpeed);
        $('#tab_description div > div').show();
        $(x).addClass("active");
        $(x).nextUntil('h6').slideDown(swapSpeed).promise().then(function() {
          //$('body, html').css('height', 'auto');
          scrollToTab($(x));
        });
      } else {
         $('#tab_description h6').removeClass("active");
         if ($(x).next("p").css('display') == 'none') {
          $('#tab_description div > div').show();
          $(x).nextUntil('h6').slideDown(swapSpeed).promise().then(function() {
            //$('body, html').css('height', 'auto');
            scrollToTab($(x));
          });
        } else {
          //$('body, html').css('height', 'auto');
          $(accordionContent).slideUp(swapSpeed);
        }
      }


      return false;

    }

    function scrollToTab(x) {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(x).offset().top - 10
      }, scrollSpeed);
    }

    //load default
    //$(function() {

      if (isMobileLandscapeOnly.matches || isTabletLandscapeOnly.matches) {
          //alert("Mobile / Tablet (Portrait)");
          desktopTabs();
          //$('#tab_description h6').on("click, tap", tabClick);

          //console.log(originalTabs);
        } else if (isMobilePortraitOnly.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches) {
          //alert("Mobile / Tablet (Portrait)");
          mobileTabs();
          //$('#tab_description h6').on("click, tap", tabClick);

        } else if (isDesktop) {
          //alert("Desktop");
          desktopTabs();
        }

    //});

  });
```

HTML Example:

```
<div class="originalTabs">
  <h6>title 1</h6>
  <p>tab 1 content</p>
  <h6>title 2</h6>
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
  <h6>title 3</h6>
  <p>tab 3 content</p>
</div>
```

JS takes above to create a generate tabs which works but if in the editor has blank  breaks so need to check and remove before creating

```
<div class="originalTabs">
  <h6>title 1</h6>
  <p>tab 1 content</p>
  <h6><span></span></h6>
  <h6>title 2</h6>
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
  <h6></h6>
  <h6>title 3</h6>
  <p>tab 3 content</p>
</div>
```

Really, need to find the empty  and  and remove

tpl source

```
<div class="originalTabs">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <!--holder for h6 tabs -->
  </ul>

  <div id="tab_description">
    <h6>title 1</h6>
    <p>tab 1 content</p>
    <h6>title 2</h6>
    <p>tab 2 content</p>
    <p>tab 2 content</p>
    <p>tab 2 content</p>
    <h6>title 3</h6>
    <p>tab 3 content</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is the HTML?

Comment: HTML is generated, ill give an example

Comment: Updated with example HTML with how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for each `h6` that has no text by this expression;

> ```
>  if(!$(this).text().trim().length)
> ```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2378768/2813224)

If it doesn't work you'll see 2 red bordered boxes.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('h6').each(function() {
  if(!$(this).text().trim().length) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.empty {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="originalTabs">
  <h6>title 1</h6>
  <p>tab 1 content</p>
  <h6 class='empty'><span></span></h6>
  <h6>title 2</h6>
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
  <p>tab 2 content</p>
  <h6 class='empty'></h6>
  <h6>title 3</h6>
  <p>tab 3 content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My code here, I think you want something like this, but the css will have some problems need to handle after you remove the h6 tag.

Remarks: you should check why your program will make a empty tag.

Reference:

https://api.jquery.com/empty/   -- move the value and keep the tag.

https://api.jquery.com/remove/  -- remove the whole tag.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<html>
    <h6>abc</h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6></h6>
    <h6>abc</h6>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var list = $("html").find("h6");
    console.log(list);
    $.each(list, function( index, value ) {
      if (value.innerText  == ""){
        list[index].remove();
      }
    });
});

</script>
```